# Questions about the game-play of Cluedo

Tags: cluedo

While playing the game, "Cluedo: Discover the Secrets," we always seem to have an argument about what we can do and what we can't. So, I've came here to put the questions to rest and hopefully have them answered.

### Case 1:

Assume I am in the Living Room, and I roll a 10. I walk toward the observatory and enter the room. Can I use the secret passage to go to the Kitchen on that same turn? Same idea should apply to other secret passage rooms.

### Case 2:

Does the pool count as a room? I ask this question because the new Cluedo requires you to go to the Pool to make the accusation. So, if one was White, she has the power to go to any room that doesn't have a secret passage. Does that power extend to going to the pool and making the accusation? Same question for the intrigue card of similar ability.

### Case 3:

The Patio's doors are unclear in the board. Does it have one door or multiple ones? There is a bench that seems to be a door and their a stairway that seems to a decorative element of the room. Which is what?

I would appreciate any answers. Further, if someone has a reputable site that explains such cases and rules in detail, then can someone please add its in his/her answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Case 1:** No, you must stop movement [upon entering a room](http://www.theartofmurder.com/table/clueboardgames/dts/dtsi4lg.jpg).

> **Rules for Moving** - If you enter a Room, STOP MOVING.

**Case 2:** Yes, the pool is a room. Someone contacted the designer, Rob Daviau, and [he confirmed this](http://boardgamegeek.com/article/8132068#8132068). He also notes that using this power only happens during the move phase **instead** of rolling. (I.e. You cannot start a rumor in another room, then warp to the **Pool** to make an accusation.)

> *Q. The Pool (1) Is the pool a room?*
>
> **A: Yes.**
>
> *Q: (2) Can this be used as a kind of "fast effect" anytime during her turn, or is it only applicable during her "move phase"?*
>
> **A: Only on her move phase, instead of rolling.**

**Case 3:** The patio has 4 entrances. They start at the white steps which connect to the house and [descend to ground level](http://www.theartofmurder.com/table/clueboardgames/dts/dtsboardlg.jpg). No doors are printed on the board for this room, unlike older editions of Clue that actually write "**DOOR**" directly on the board. The **Patio** is based on the older edition's **Ballroom** and has a similar floor-plan. (The whole house does actually, albeit rotated 90 degrees in the linked image)

[image: Classic Clue]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don' think you understood my question for case 2. Regardless, I reckon White does indeed have the ability to move to the pool to make an accusation.

Comment: The card says verbatim, "Once per game, you may move to any room that does not have a secret passage."  There is nothing that says that the pool isn't a room. But, its clear from the cards that the pool isn't a murder room, thus being excluded from the rumors.

Comment: Once again, thanks for your informative and detailed answer.

Answer (score -2):

I disagree. If the pool was a room then there would be a room card for it. White becomes too powerful if she can move there without rolling. Plus Mel always chooses White and I'm tired of her beating me!